# Passing constant parameter to simulink s-function (mdlderivatives)

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have build a model in MATLAB and i am using SIMULINK to solve the differential equation.

```
function sys=mdlDerivatives(t,x,u)
% Constant block
n    = 10; % fixed switch exponent
k1   = u(2);% input rate constant (1/min)
k2   = u(3);% output rate constant (1/min)
Td   = 70; % time delay (min)
Alfa = 0.7;% ug per 100 ml
Beta = 1;% ug per 100 ml
f    = 250; % phase (min)

a=Alfa*cos((t-f)*2*pi()/1440) + Beta;
Sigmoid = a^n*u(4)/(a^n + u(4)^n);
dxdt(1) = k1*Sigmoid -k2*x(1);
sys = [dxdt];
```

I want to send the value of Alfa from the base workspace.

```
tspan=[0:0.05:1400]'; 
x0=1.7;              
PARAMETERS=simset('InitialState',x0,'Solver','ode15s','MaxStep',0.05,'OutputPoints','specified','RelTol',1E-6);
[tdata,y]=sim('cortisol_model_2',tspan,PARAMETERS);
```

I tried using From Workspace in the simulink block but I am only able to insert a vector from that. So is there a better way to pass a constant parameter to the mdlfunction. I actually want to pass different values of alpha to check the sensitivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be writing any new code using level-2 m-code S-functions.  Level-1 functionality only exists for backwards compatibility.

Nonetheless, to pass parameters into a level-1 S-function you do the following:

Within the Primary/main/first function

```
function [sys,x0,str,ts,simStateCompliance] = sfuntmpl(t,x,u,flag,p1,p2,p3)
...
switch flag,
...
  case 1,
    sys=mdlDerivatives(t,x,u,p1,p2,p3);

...
```

And with `mdlDerivatives`

```
function sys=mdlDerivatives(t,x,u,p1,p2,p3)
...
% use p1, p2 and/or p3 here
...
```